# copy data of a column to other tables column for which id compares

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

I have two tables :

```
 map_sale_product(id, sale_id, product_id)
```

&

```
 sale_order(id,name,....).
```

I added a column for prd_id in sale_order. now I want to copy all the data of product_id from map_sale_product to product_id of sale_order.

Condition is, data should be copy if `sale_id(map_sale_product)` and `id(sale_order)` matches.

Is there any way to do it in mysql?
PLZ.. tell a way do it on mysql-workbench..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want insert  the rows  then you can use an insert select

```
insert into sale_order (col1, col2, col3...)
select cola, colb, col3 ...
from map_sale_product
```

instead if you need  an updated for existing rows  you can use  update with inner join

```
  update sale_order a 
  inner join map_sale_product b  on a.sale_id =b.sale_id
  set a.col1 = b.colA,
      a.col2, = b.colB, 
      ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use this query for copy data from map_sale_product table to sale_order table by using join query with update:

```
UPDATE sale_order so
    JOIN map_sale_product ms ON so.sale_id = ms.id
SET ms.product_id = so.product_id
```